# Close Shadowbox window and redirect while refreshing

Tags: php, javascript

I am using some JavaScript code that closes a Shadowbox window on success and redirects to a PHP file, but it doesn't seem to work.  Closing the window is working but not redirecting. Why?

```
success: function(){
    $('#spinnerDiv').empty();
    $('.success0').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    window.parent.Shadowbox.close();
    window.location.href = 'view_ad.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to redirect the right object - which is the parent, as in window.*parent*.location.href.

```
success: function(){
    $('#spinnerDiv').empty();
    $('.success0').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    window.parent.Shadowbox.close();
     window.parent.location.href = 'view_ad.php'; 
}
```